# Ionic 2 Can't resolve all parameters for InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I don't understand why I get the following error when I use the native InAppBrowser plugin : Can't resolve all parameters for InAppBrowser

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-sign-in',
  templateUrl: 'sign-in.html',
  providers: [ InAppBrowser ]
})
export class SignInPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, public inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser ) {


  };

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add `InAppBrowser` to the providers array and you also don't need to inject it in the constructor.

Simply import it in the beginning of the page (as you did), and then use it anywhere in the code like that:

```
openPage() {
  new InAppBrowser('https://google.com', '_system');
}
```