# Correct way to import Horizon IO into angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, horizon

The way I'm currently importing HorizonIO into my angular 2 project is as follows:

```
var horizon = require('@horizon/client');

@Injectable()
export class DbService {
    private horizon;

    constructor() {
        this.horizon = Horizon({host: 'localhost:8181'});
    }
}
```

Now I don't feel that this is the correct way as I should simply be able to

```
import { Horizon } from '@horizon/client';
```

Although it doesn't throw an error, the variable isn't usable.

Thought/comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ES6 import equivalent of

```
var Horizon = require('@horizon/client');
```

is

```
import * as Horizon from '@horizon/client';
```

What you did is the equivalent of

```
var Horizon = require('@horizon/client').Horizon;
```

---

edit:

I now use the following code to make horizon injectable:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Hz from '@horizon/client';

@Injectable()
export class Horizon extends Function {
  private _hz;

  constructor() {
    super('...args', 'return this._hz(...args)');
    this._hz = new Hz({host: 'localhost:8181'});

    return this.bind(this);
  }
}
```

It can then be injected and called like you would when directly importing it:

```
constructor(hz: Horizon){
  hz('messages').watch().subscribe(...);
}
```

Not exactly sure if this has any benefits over importing Horizon directly, but it feels more angularish to use DI.

Comment: Thank you, import * as Horizon from '@horizon/client' is indeed correct

Answer (score 0):

Check if `@horizon/client` is in your `node_modules` folder, if not : try to `npm install` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@horizon/client).

Comment: @horizon/client is present in my node_modules folder

Comment: @woodsprite Try to import it in the constructor of your componennt : like `constructor(public horizon: Horizon){}`

Comment: I thought it worked at first but it throws: "Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Service"

Comment: Maybe try :  `constructor(@Inject(Horizon horizon: Horizon)` and `import { Inject } from '@angular/core` ?

Comment: Or maybe try to follow this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528502/ionic-2-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-inappbrowser) . It seems like you don't need to inject it in your constructor :)

Comment: I really appreciate the effort but nothing so far has worked, luckily it's not that big of a deal and I'm only asking for best-practice reasons