# ionic 3 : Can't resolve all parameters for SQLiteObject: (?)

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm using Ionic 3 SQLite native plugin from [Here(Ionicframework.com)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/), and Here's my constructor code :

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
            public menu: MenuController, 
            translate: TranslateService,
            private tts: TextToSpeech,
            private sqlite: SQLite) {

   this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'data.db',
      location: 'default'
      }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        db.executeSql('create table IF NOT EXISTS `localflags`(`flag1` VARCHAR(10),`flag2` VARCHAR(10),`flag3` VARCHAR(10), `flag4` VARCHAR(10));', {})
          .then(() => console.log('Table created!!!'))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
      }).catch(e => console.log(e));
        }
```

So, when I run it on device using "ionic cordova run android -lc" it give me this error,

`Can't resolve all parameters for SQLiteObject: (?)`

This code is from the ionic native documentation. This is very basic code, and I'm new to this, so I can't figure out what's wrong with this.

Any help will be appreciated. And if someone can point me to the Ionic 3 SQLite tutorials , that will be great. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, the case was, I had Done `import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';` this in my ts file, So I thought both SQLite and SQLiteObject are needed to imported in `app.module.ts` file, but after reading   [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528502/ionic-2-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-inappbrowser), I removed `SQLiteObject` from `app.module.ts` file and also removed injection of SQLite from the constructor and it worked.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue :) Please mark this answer as the accepted answer so we can close the issue (I think it can be done in two days...)

Comment: Yes, will have to wait for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add "/ngx" on your import line

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';
```

Besides, you don't have to add **SQLiteObject** in the **providers** array of **app.module.ts** file